# How do I choose the position of the cursor when a user is inputting information in python?

Tags: python

Sorry If my code seems off, this is my first time asking here and I am somewhat new to python.

I want a user to give me the number of sets and reps for a workout.
Here is my code below:

```
print("Please enter the number of sets you would like to do followed by the number of reps. ")
sets, reps = input("Pushup- \n\t" + "Sets: " + "Reps: ").split()
```

So when I run this, naturally the cursor will be flashing at the end of "reps:" however what I want it to do is so that when I run it, the cursor will flash after "sets:" and when the user hits the space key, it will move all the way over to after "reps:".

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just having it as two inputs:

```
sets = input("Pushup-Sets: ")
reps = input("Pushup-Reps: ")
```

Is there a particular reason you need it done in one line?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try doing something like this:

```
print("Please enter the number of sets you would like to do followed by the 
number of reps.")
print("Pushup-")
sets = input("Sets:")
reps = input("Reps:")
```

It uses the return button instead of the spacebar, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested, having it as two separate inputs will be much easier.

If you do want to make a text-based app which does it the way you've described, the library you're looking for is called "curses" (see: [howto](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html), [reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html)).

However, it seems like a bit of an anachronism; for a quick app, separate inputs are much easier, and for a user-friendly app you'll probably want a graphical interface (or web) rather than a text-based one.